# Is it possible to use latest version (v3) of AWS PHP SDK to deal with Ceph storage?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, ceph

I'm trying to deal with a Ceph storage using Amazon S3 APIs. Everything works with the version 1 and 2 of the PHP SDK, but I would like to use the latest version (v3). The Ceph documentation deals with SDK version 1, while I found on the RedHat website documentation about version 2, but nothing about version 3. Despite my attempts, no way I can make it work. Do you know if it is simply not possible? If it is possible, can you give me a short example?
Thank you in advance.